# Calculate DateDiff in PHP in minutes

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

$sql_apr = " SELECT SUM ( meter * minute ) FROM table";
$rs_apr = @mysql_query($sql_apr);
$total_apr = @mysql_fetch_array($rs_apr);
$try4 = $total_apr['SUM(meter * minute'];

while ($rs_t = @mysql_fetch_array($rs_t)) {
    $minute = '';

    $sql_t = "SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'e_date e_time','s_date s_time') AS minute";
    $rs_t = @mysql_query($sql_t);
    $minute = $rs_t['minute'];
}
```

?>

Comment: format code to make it readable.

Comment: What result give you that query used directly in database ?

Comment: It should give total of minute x meter. But I need to find value of minute first.

Comment: You should edit your question to include what you are trying to achieve. There is no question in there now. The definition of your table would be nice too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong result:

```
$rs_t=@mysql_query($sql_t);
$minute = $total_t['minute'];
```

should be

```
$rs_t=@mysql_query($sql_t);
$minute = $rs_t['minute'];
//         ^ use the rs_t result, not the result from the first query
```

You are also result the variable that you are looping on. I highly doubt that this while loop will ever end. You are looping on the result from `$rs_t` and then you reassign `$rs_t` inside the loop.

Comment: still return O result.

Comment: Where did your code go?

Comment: I want to get value of minute before I want to sum with meter. Could anyone help me how to get it?
tq

Answer (score 0):

why don't you do this in correct order

```
$query = "SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'e_date e_time','s_date s_time') AS minute";
$results = @mysql_query($query);
$row = @mysql_fetch_array($results);
$minute = $row['minute'];

print_r($minute);

$sql_apr = " SELECT SUM ( meter * " . $minute . " ) AS my_sum FROM table";
$rs_apr = @mysql_query($sql_apr);
$total_apr = @mysql_fetch_array($rs_apr);
$try4 = $total_apr['my_sum'];
```

You try to get result (in `while`) before you run query.

**edit:**

```
$query = "SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'s_date s_time','e_date e_time') AS minute";
```

Comment: tq. but it 's still won't work.

Comment: I can't test it. Did you test both queries directly in database ? You can add `print_r($minute);` to test result of first query.

Comment: and now this happen in my sql

"Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF"

Comment: See MySQL docs: [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) expect only two arguments - dates.

Comment: Maybe you need [TIMEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

Comment: Or [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) to get result in minutes.

Comment: I used TIMESTAMPDIFF. but it return result -60. It should 60.
start 14:00
end 15:00

Comment: put start time as first - `TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'s_date s_time','e_date e_time')`

Comment: why it return total (5) rows?

Comment: It undefined variable minute.

Comment: If you use `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(...) FROM table_name` and `table_name` has 5 rows than you get 5 results.

Comment: Where do you get `undefined variable minute` ? Directly in database for `SELECT SUM (meter * minute) FROM table` ? `minute` is unknown for database or database expect column with name `minute`.

Comment: I don't know your tables and what result you exacly expect but maybe you need one query `SELECT SUM(meter * TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, 's_date s_time', 'e_date e_time')) FROM table;`

Comment: why it appear this "FUNCTION database_name.SUM does not exist."

Comment: SELECT SUM(meter * TIMESTAMPDIFF( 
MINUTE , '2013-04-88 14:00', '2013-04-88 15:00' ) ) AS 
monthly FROM table1
it return column monthly [Null]

Comment: SUM is standalone function, not part of some database - you can't use `database_name.SUM`

Comment: You get `null` because there is no date like `2013-04-88`

Comment: i get it. but here's the codes
SELECT SUM('21.46' * TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'2013-04-08 14:00','2013-04-08 15:00')) AS MONTHLY FROM table1
it return me 2575.2000000000003
it should 1287.6

Comment: $sql = "SELECT SUM('meter' * TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'s_date s_time','e_date e_time')) AS ??? FROM table1";
 $rs=@mysql_query($sql);
 $total=@mysql_fetch_array($rs);
 $try4 = $total['???'];//what should i put in ???

Comment: `table1` has 2 rows and your result is doubled. For static values use `SELECT SUM('21.46' * TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'2013-04-08 14:00','2013-04-08 15:00')) AS monthly;` without `FROM table_name`. If you need to sum elements from `table1` you can use `SELECT SUM(name_of_column_with_meter * TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,name_of_column_with_start_time,name_of_column_with_end_time)) AS monthly FROM table1;`

Comment: For `???` use what you wish. You can even use `big_yellow_submarine` but don't use spaces, native chars, sql keywords.

Comment: Actually table1 has 2 rows for April. I want to calculate sum_row1 + sum_row2 = total. And total is my end result. So how i'm gonna edit my codes?

Comment: If `table1` has columns `meter`, `s_date`, `s_time`, `e_date`, `e_time` you need something similar to `SELECT SUM(meter * TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,CONCAT(s_date,' ',s_time),CONCAT(e_date,' ',e_time))) AS total FROM table1;`

Comment: it still return double result. :(

Comment: Are you sure `1287.6` is correct result ? It seems to me that `sum_row1 = 1287.6` and `sum_row2 = 1287.6` so `total = sum_row1 + sum_row2 = 1287.6 + 1287.6 = 2575.2`

Comment: very sure. Because each row had different record.

Comment: So I'm confuse - This give you result for each row using records in that row (you can test it in database to see results) `SELECT meter * TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,CONCAT(s_date,' ',s_time),CONCAT(e_date,' ',e_time)) AS row_result FROM table1;` and then I use `SUM()` to add that (individual) results and get `total`. It seems I don't understand your problem. You can get result for first row using `LIMIT 1` (for second row `LIMIT 1,1`) and probably you get `1287.6` `SELECT meter * ... FROM table1 LIMIT 1;` See: [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c721/6).

Comment: I had tried that one. and here my result. [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ed0f/2)

Comment: could you help me? I tried many time. :( [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a4b8/6)

Comment: In first [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ed0f/2) you forgot `,` (and space between date and time) `CONCAT('2013-04-08', ' ', '15:00')` (but for static values you don't need CONCATenation - you could use only string `'2013-04-08 15:00'`). Btw: your `s_time` (15:00) is later than e_time (14:00) so I get minutes with minus [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ed0f/7)

Comment: second [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a4b8/6) - sqlFiddle is tool for testing only SQL query and You mix SQL with PHP.

Comment: In SQL you can use `DATEFDIFF` to get number of days in month [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a4b8/43)

Comment: Actually I want to find the numberofdays first, then multiply it with meter for each month in a year. So how I can fix this codes. I know it mix SQL with PHP,just I want to show it to you. [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2159c/12)

Comment: In SQL you can use `DATEDIFF` or `DAY(LAST_DAY('2013-04-01'))` [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2159c/20)

Comment: could you give me sample of calc_days_in_month. I tried many time,but it's wont work. "Warning: calc_days_in_month() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given" $month='month'; $year='year'

Comment: See in PHP docs: [calc_days_in_month](http://pl1.php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php). Arguments have to be `int` ([integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)) not `string`. And `long` means only `long int` (in C/C++). In `long` you can keep bigger (longer) numbers than in `int`. Example: `echo cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 4, 2013);` or `$month=4; $year=2013; cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);`